# Unable to Connect Flask App on render.com to PostgreSQL Database

Tags: database, postgresql, flask

I am trying to connect my Flask application, deployed on render.com, to a PostgreSQL database. The database is already working with my development app, but I am encountering an error when trying to connect from the deployed app.

I am using the normal format for DATABASE_URL='postgres:{username}@{host}:{port}/{database_name}'

I have made the following changes to the pg_hba.conf and postgresql.conf files, and have restarted with postgresql with brew:

pg_hba.conf:

```
local   all             all                                     md5
host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            trust
host    all             all             ::1/128                 trust
host    all             all             0.0.0.0/0               trust
```

postgresql.conf:

```
listen_addresses = '*'  # what IP address(es) to listen on;
                        # comma-separated list of addresses;
                        # defaults to 'localhost'; use '*' for all
                        # (change requires restart)
```

Despite these changes, I am still getting the following error when trying to connect:

```
Error connecting to database: (psycopg2.OperationalError) connection to server at "localhost" (::1), port 5432 failed: 
Connection refused Is the server running on that host and accepting TCP/IP connections? 
connection to server at "localhost" (127.0.0.1), port 5432 failed: 
Connection refused Is the server running on that host and accepting TCP/IP connections? 
(Background on this error at: https://sqlalche.me/e/20/e3q8)
```

Is there something else I need to configure or modify to successfully connect my Flask app to the PostgreSQL database on render.com?

Comment: The issue is not with `pg_hba.conf`. It is that this `'postgres:{username}@{host}:{port}/{database_name}'` is pointing  at an instance that does not exist or is blocked. Given that the `host` in the error is `localhost` I'm betting the Postgres instance is actually located somewhere else.

Comment: It is localhost. But I don’t understand because it is currently working perfectly fine with my development app. It’s only when I copy and paste the same string to use as an env variable in render.com that it shows the error.

Comment: The error is telling you that Postgres is not listening on `localhost`. I don't use Render, but I'm guessing the answer lies here [Database connection](https://docs.render.com/databases).